# How to convert a non-linear constraint to a linear constraint for integer programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I have non-linear scheduling model and I want to convert it to a linear model. But I have no idea about how can I do it.

**The nonlinear constraint is:**

For each $i, i'\in I$ and $j, j' \in J$ and $q, q' \in Q$ and $k \in K$

$$s_{ij} \geq (\sum_{q'=q}^5 o_{i'j'q'} * c_{i'j'} * x_{i'j'k}) * x_{ijk}*o_{ijq}$$

In this constraint:

**$s$** is continuous positive variable,

**$o$** and **$x$** are binary variables

I can do the $x_{ijk}*o_{ijq}$ part using a Big M number but I don't know any about the summation inside the paranthesis. How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the summation. You will get something like $\sum c \cdot o \cdot x \cdot x \cdot o$. This is `constant * binary * binary * binary * binary`. The multiplication of 4 binary variables $y=x_1x_2x_3x_4$ can be linearized as: 
\begin{align}
  &y \le x_i \\
  &y \ge x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4-3 \\
  &y \in \{0,1\} \>\text{(note: $y$ can even be relaxed to continuous)}  
\end{align}
No big-Ms needed I think.

Comment: That's a good solution. You are the only person who answer such questions:) Thanks for all @Erwin.

Comment: By the way, the variable c is not constraint, it is a continuous variable. It was my fault cause I forgot it to add.

Comment: In my case it was like this z1 = x0 * y1, i convert to linear equation like   z1 ≤ x1 and z1  ≥ x0 + y0 -1 .  zi, xi, yi belongs to binary {0,1}  is it correct can we write like this?

Comment: @smsivaprakaash You notation is way too sloppy to answer this (x0 vs x1??).  You probably should ask again but a bit more precisely.