# Linearized Michaelis-Menten equation for LP

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, chemistry, mathematical-biology

I am attempting to include the [Michaelis-Menten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) equation in (continuous) variables $S$ and $v$

$$v=\frac{V_{\max} S}{K_m + S}$$

where $V_{\max}$ and $K_m$ are given constants, as a linear programming constraint.

Similar inquiries about linearizing non-linear expressions suggest that [binary variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798077/how-to-convert-a-non-linear-constraint-to-a-linear-constraint-for-integer-progra) and [variable splitting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020405/converting-an-non-linear-problem-to-linear-linear-programming) are potential strategies, but I cannot visualize how to apply these techniques (or if these are applicable) to the [Michaelis-Menten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) equation without introducing a non-linear equality.

How can the equation be adapted into a linear system that is compatible with linear programming?

I appreciate your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(t) = \frac{at}{b+t}$$ Taking the reciprocal, you get $$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{f(t)}
&= \frac{b+t}{at} \\
&= (\frac{b}{a})(\frac{1}{t}) + \frac{1}{a} \\
\end{align*}$$ Letting $\tilde{y}(t) = \frac{1}{f(t)}$, $\tilde{m} = \frac{b}{a}$, $\tilde{t} = \frac{1}{t}$, and $\tilde{b} = \frac{1}{a}$, you get $$\tilde{y}(t) = \tilde{m}\tilde{t} + \tilde{b}$$ You now have a linear equation where you can optimize for the parameters $\tilde{m}$ and $\tilde{b}$.